# Query in MognoDB using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

lets say my Documents looks like this.

```
name: "Foo Bar"
dob: "Foo Bar"
type: "Foo Bar"
objects: ["1", "2", "3"]
```

now i have a one array.

```
some_array = ["1", "5", "6"]
```

now i want to run query such that if any value of **some_array** match the any value of **objects from documents** it will return the results from collection.

I have tried query using combination of QUERY AN ARRAY + $elemMatch + $in but nothing works.

How can i make that possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `$in` operator should be all you need:

```
db.collection.find({objects:{$in:["1","5","6"]}})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xW-5EnlWpcA)